# GCP Compute Instance stuck "stopping"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a few GCP computer instances that I have tried to shut down (not delete) from the console, and they are stuck with a spinning circle and the status "stopping".

They've been like this for about 4 days now.

I've tried to stop using gcloud cli too, but that fails with an internal error.

Anyone got any advice please?

Comment: Without details on the VMs, contact Google Cloud Support. Some older versions of Linux have problems with ACPI notifying the virtualization host that the VM is stopped.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I don't know how to contact Google Cloud Support as I'm not on a paid support plan unfortunately! These VM's are debian 10, so not too old!

Answer (score 0):

If the gcloud command line is unable to stop the instance then, you can take a look into [activity log](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) or [stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#explore) which will help you to debug further.

Generally, When there will be an outage or OMG at google end this kind of issue happens. Once the issue is resolved at Google end then automatically it resolves in our consoles or Projects too.

For free tier accounts there is no support given by google but we can describe our issue [here](https://support.google.com/cloud#topic=3340599) and [get support](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#support).